# Kafka rebalance at the group name level?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 3 topics A,B,C with same number of partitions. I use the same group name for all the consumers to this topics. 
  My questions are:

1. If a consumer for one of the topics/partitions will rebalance be triggered for the other two topics consumers?
2. Same if adding a new partition for one topic, will rebalance be triggered for the other two topics consumers?
3. More general, the consumers rebalance occurs at the group level no matter from what topics are consuming (considering they have the same group name)?

I look forward for your answers.

Regards,
 Florin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

On rebalance, from a logical point of view, the previous (global) partitions assignment gets invalidated and each partition gets reassigned.

See FAQ ["Can I predict the results of the consumer rebalance?"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-CanIpredicttheresultsoftheconsumerrebalance?)